# unidirectional one to one saving gives HHH000099: an assertion failure occurred: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, java-8

I have a 1:1 unidirectional relation between Building (parent) and Rib (child) in a MySQL database.
The id of the Rib table is foreign key referencing the key in the Building table.
The project is using Java 8 with Spring Boot.

This is the Rib class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rib")
@AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "date_created", column = @Column(name = "date_created", nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "date_modified", column = @Column(name = "dateModified", nullable = false)) })
@DynamicUpdate
public class Rib extends BaseEntityModel implements BaseEntity<Integer>, HistoryEntity, VersionableEntity {

    @HistoryIgnore
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5024158201985145872L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_building")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "iban", nullable = false)
    private String iban;

    @Column(name = "bic", nullable = false)
    private String bic;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Short version;

    @HistoryIgnore
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_building")
    @MapsId
    @NotNull
    private Building building;

    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // other getters and setters, hashCode, equals, toString
    
    

    @Override
    public Set<Integer> getParentsForHistory() {
        Set<Integer> parents = new HashSet<>();
        parents.add(TopLevelHistoryEntities.getParentMask(building.getId(), building.getClass()));
        return parents;
    }
```

The service method which fails:

```
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public RibDTO add(RibDTO ribDTO) {
        Building building = buildingRepository.findById(ribDTO.getId()).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Building not found"));
        securityUtils.userHasAccessToRib(building);

        Rib rib = ribConverter.convertFromDto(ribDTO);
        rib.setBuilding(building);
        rib.setDateCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
        rib.setDateModified(LocalDateTime.now());

        Rib save = ribRepository.save(rib); // fails here
        return ribConverter.convertToDto(save);
    }
```

*ribRepository* is an interface extending *JpaRepository*

```
RibConverter class:
@Component
public class RibConverter extends AbstractDtoConverter<Rib, RibDTO> {
    @Override
    public RibDTO convertToDto(Rib convert) {
        RibDTO ribDTO = new RibDTO();
        ribDTO.setId(convert.getId());
        ribDTO.setName(convert.getName());
        ribDTO.setIban(convert.getIban());
        ribDTO.setBic(convert.getBic());
        ribDTO.setDateCreated(convert.getDateCreated());
        ribDTO.setDateModified(convert.getDateModified());
        ribDTO.setVersion(convert.getVersion());
        return ribDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public Rib convertFromDto(RibDTO convert) {
        Rib rib = new Rib();
        rib.setId(convert.getId());
        rib.setName(convert.getName());
        rib.setIban(convert.getIban());
        rib.setBic(convert.getBic());
        rib.setDateCreated(convert.getDateCreated());
        rib.setDateModified(convert.getDateModified());
        rib.setVersion(convert.getVersion());
        return rib;
    }

}
```

This is the console log (with `logging.level.org.hibernate=trace`):
https://pastebin.com/k0Xdz2jL

How can I solve it?